# Function is behaving like it destroys the table inside the if statement

Tags: c, brute-force

It does returns the i value since for some reason it does not adds +1 to the counter and it cannot enter the if statement

The function is supposed to be returning the starting position of the word hi when it matches it with the other table since it is comparing them.
It takes the table from main as I tested in the start of the for with a print but It does not print the table after the for

```c
int Brute_Force(char array[],char key[])  
{
    int i,j,flag=0;
    for(i=0; i<=8; i++)  
    {
       for(j=0; j<2; j++) 
        {
            if(array[i+j]=!key[j]) 
            {
                flag=0;
            }
            if(array[i+j]==key[j])
            {
                flag=flag+1;
            }
            if(flag == 2)
            {
                return i;
            }


        }
    }
   return -1;  
}
int main()
{
   int show;

 char A[10] = {'o','h',' ','h','i',' ','m','i','k','e'};
 char B[2] = {'h','i'};  


 show = Brute_Force(A,B); 

   printf("%d",show);

}
```

Comment: `array[i+j] = !key[j]` should be `array[i+j] != key[j]`

Comment: You should be adding `const` to pointer parameters that point to something you don't intend to change. It would have found the problem, for starters.

Comment: that ain't it I corrected it before posting here I just forgot copy pasta again thanks though

Comment: `flag` should be set to zero inside the "`i`" loop. The first `if` should `break` instead of clearing the flag. The third `if` should be inside the body of the second.

Comment: @JAntoniou I tested the code, the only difference being that I changed `array[i+j] = !key[j]` to be `array[i+j] != key[j]` and it actually does what you want, it returns the start index  of `key` in `array`. I also added `getchar()` after the `printf` to prevent the program from quickly closing right after printing the value, now it waits for you to hit the `enter` key.

Comment: flag should be set to zero inside the "i" loop. The first if should break instead of clearing the flag. The third if should be inside the body of the second.

It works after these changes for me, thanks everyone